# unable to transfer file to ftp server using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ftp, file-transfer, xp-cmdshell

I'am using this code to transfer a file from my local system to a ftp (I have all the read and write rights for this ftp).

```
        if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[s_ftp_PutFile]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
        drop procedure [dbo].[s_ftp_PutFile]
        GO

        Create procedure s_ftp_PutFile
        @FTPServer  varchar(128) ,
        @FTPUser    varchar(128) ,
        @FTPPWD     varchar(128) ,
        @FTPPath    varchar(128) ,
        @FTPFileName    varchar(128) ,

        @SourcePath varchar(128) ,
        @SourceFile varchar(128) ,

        @workdir    varchar(128)
        as
        /*
        exec s_ftp_PutFile  
                @FTPServer = '172.*****' ,
                @FTPUser = 'username' ,
                @FTPPWD = 'password' ,
                @FTPPath = '/dir1/' ,
                @FTPFileName = 'test2.txt' ,
                @SourcePath = 'c:\vss\mywebsite\' ,
                @SourceFile = 'test2.txt' ,

                @workdir = 'c:\temp\'
        */

        declare @cmd varchar(1000)
        declare @workfilename varchar(128)

            select @workfilename = 'ftpcmd.txt'

            -- deal with special characters for echo commands
            select @FTPServer = replace(replace(replace(@FTPServer, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
            select @FTPUser = replace(replace(replace(@FTPUser, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
            select @FTPPWD = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPWD, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
            select @FTPPath = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPath, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')

            select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + 'open ' + @FTPServer
                    + ' > ' + @workdir + @workfilename
            exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
            select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + @FTPUser
                    + '>> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
            exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
            select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + @FTPPWD
                    + '>> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
            exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
            select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + 'put ' + @SourcePath + @SourceFile + ' ' + @FTPPath + @FTPFileName
                    + ' >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
            exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
            select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + 'quit'
                    + ' >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
            exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

            select @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @workdir + @workfilename

            create table #a (id int identity(1,1), s varchar(1000))
            insert #a
            exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

            select id, ouputtmp = s from #a
        go
```

I am unable to transfer the file and getting this error

1   User (172.******:(none)): open 172.******

2   NULL

3   NULL

4   put c:\vss\mywebsite\test2.txt  /dir1/test2.txt

5   c:\vss\mywebsite\test2.txt: File not found

6   quit

7   NULL

however i am able to transfer through cmd prompt.

Comment: Generate the code from the procedure, put it in a batch file and then execute it. If the code is working without you changing anything then sql doesent have enough permissions. Also use `sftp` instead of `ftp` its more secure.

Comment: hey subquerycrunch so it means the above code is fine. I am still getting the same error of file not found Is there any other way of doing this without making a batch file.

Comment: You know that when you execute your code its executed on the machine hosting the sql server, for example:
On your pc you have a file C:\asd.txt and when you run the batch it works.
You are running the code on the server so it searches for the file on the server and there the file really does not exist.
So you must copy the location of your file from your sql server machine .. cuz sql does not work with your local paths.

Comment: so what should i do to transfer many files to ftp server using sql procedure only. let me know if you have any link to sort out all this.

Comment: Are you hosting your sql server locally?

Comment: yes i am hosting it locally

Answer (score 0):

can sql do other things as the command line?

also, that uid ss is using on the command line, does it have rights to talk from the ss machine to the destination? many enterprises don't allow "service" ids to talk willy nilly over the network to anyone it wants to. it may need rights to make that connection.